# Probability paradox (no it's not but can someone explain)

Tags: probability

In this little problem:
Amédée, Barnabé, Charles shoot a bird; if the probability of success is for Amédée: 70%, Barnabé:
50%, Charles: 90%, what is the probability that the bird will be hit?

I responded this way: a probability of 70% means that in 70 out of 100 cases the target is hit, so let's suppose that Amédée, Barnabé, Charles shoot 100 shot each one, the numbers of times they hit the target will be (70+50+90)/300 = 70% .

But the solution the book says is: Let us rather consider the complementary event: the bird is not touched if it is not touched either by Amédée, neither by Barnabas nor by Charles. This event has the probability: (1−0.7)·(1−0.5)·(1−0.9) =0.015.

The probability that the bird is hit is therefore: 1−0.015 = 0.985
which is 98.5%. Can someone explain where am I wrong (I know I am)?

Comment: Some assumptions are required.  The most natural is that the shooters hit or miss *independently* of each other.  That's the assumption that motivates the official solution.  Your computation doesn't make any sense.  Why are you adding the results?  (these can't be disjoint events).  Why are you dividing by $300$?

Comment: @lulu I divided by 300 because I considered that each one of the shooters shoots 100 time ,so in total we have 300 shot but only (70+50+90 =210) of them hit the target

Comment: You have to think about the overlap cases (in which more than one person hits the target).   That's where the assumption of independence comes in.  Other assumptions are logically possible.  You might say that $C$ is simply better than the others and if he misses, they always miss as well.  That's a very different assumption.  The problem should have specified the intended assumption, but in this sort of problem "independence" is the standard assumption.

Comment: Intuition on why your answer is incorrect: If there is only Charles who goes bird hunting, his chance of shooting the bird is $90\%$. If Amédée and Barnabé joins Charles, it doesn't make sense that the probability is only $70\%$; with **more** people, the probability should **not decrease**!

Comment: You calculated the *average probability* for the participants to individually hit the bird.  A calculation similar to yours might have been $0.7+0.5+0.9=2.1$... *no division necessary*.  This you will recognize is not between $0$ and $1$ and so should not represent a probability and indeed it does not.  This calculation is for the *expected number of times the bird is hit* which is the right answer to the wrong problem.

Comment: In your calculation simply, the bird is shot by an average shooter. But the poor bird has to be missed $3$ times in order to survive.

Answer (score 2):

You calculated the probability that the  bird will get shot **given that Amedee, Barnebe, and Charles are drawn at random and then ONE of them shoots.** You were instead asked to calculate the probability that the [poor] bird gets shot given that **each of them gets one shot**.

**It may help to ponder the following.** If someone flips a quarter i.e., a fair coin $100$ times, then he can expect to get $50$ heads. Each time he flips he will get a head with a probability of $50\%$. Compare this to the probability that he gets heads at least once in his $100$ flips. The probability that he did not land a head even once in his $100$ flips, is $(1/2)^{100}$, which is far far less than $50/%$ and is fact fact far less than one-in-a-trillion. So the probability that he gets heads at least once is $1$ minus the less-than-one-in-a-trillion odds he gets no heads.

Answer (score 1):

You computed the average $\frac{.7+.5+.9}{3}=\frac{2.1}{3}=.7$. This tells us that if these three shooters each perform an experiment where they shoot at a bird, their average performance is $.7$. In our experiment, three shooters are shooting at the same bird.

If $A$ goes first there is a $.7$ probability that the bird is shot and a $.3$ probability that it isn't.

If $A$ misses, there is a $.5$ probability that $B$ hits the bird and a $.5$ probability that $B$ misses.

If $B$ misses, there is a $.9$ probability that $C$ hits the bird and a $.1$ probability that the bird survives.

Let $A'$ be the probability that $A$ hits the bird. Define $B'$ and $C'$ similarly.

Then the probability that the bird gets hit will be $$P(A')+P(B'|\lnot A')P(\lnot A')+ P(C'|\lnot B',\lnot A')=.7 +.5(.3)+.9(.3)(.5)=.7+.15+.135=.985$$